# Accessing nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm building an Angular App and also using angular translate as it needs to be in dual languages.

I've *seem* to have created my JSON properly (ran it through a checker), but when I try to access items within the JSON object beyond the first level, it returns undefined.

For instance, my JSON within the angular translations is this:

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
 "SEARCH": {
    "SEARCH" : "Recherce",
    "ABILITY" : "Abilities",
    "MANAGEMENT" : "Management Competencies",
    "PERSONAL" : "Personal Suitability"
 },

 "ABILITIES": {
    "TITLE" : "Test Title here",
    "ADVISORY": {
      "TITLE" : "Advisory Skills",
      "QUESTIONS": [
        {
          "TYPE" : "A",
          "LEVEL" : "45",
          "DESCRIPTION" : "Can you tell me how awesome you are"
        },
        {
          "TYPE" : "B",
          "LEVEL" : "100",
          "DESCRIPTION" : "Tell me about your wicked project"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  "HEADLINE": "Oh No!",
  "SUB_HEADLINE": "Looks like you are not amazing"
});
```

And to begin accessing the data in the JSON object, I do

```
list = $translateProvider.translations('en');
```

Now, when outputting items in the console to see if they work I do this:

```
console.log(list);
var getTitle = list.HEADLINE;
var getSearch = list.SEARCH.ABILITY;
console.log(getSearch);
console.log(getTitle);
```

This is where it gets odd.

> The 'list' returns the JSON array I specified
>
> Getting the `HEADLINE` returns `Oh No!`
>
> But getting `list.SEARCH.ABILITY` returns an `undefined`

What gives!? I haven't event tried to access the stuff I really want in the really nested array "ABILITIES"

Keep in mind that Angular Translate uses the format `{{ 'ABILITIES.ADVISORY.TITLE' | translate }}` to output the JSON onto the HTML page

Comment: Seems to work just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/z1uLjg89/ Can you provide a fiddle or snippet that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I will try, but it is very odd that getting the headline works, but NOT the SEARCH.ABILITY. I can't think of a reason why valid JSON would work with one, but not the nested one

Comment: 7 years later, I'm experiencing the same issue. Seems no solution was found, eh?

Answer (score -3):

try `list.SEARCH["ABILITY"].value`

Comment: That also returns an 'undefined'. And plus, I cannot use javascript in the HTML document, see my edit

Comment: This should be no different than `list.SEARCH.ABILITY`; did you even try your answer?

Comment: yes, it is the exact same, which makes me thing something about my syntax or JSON accessing is wrong, but I do not know what

Comment: Got it, sorry. Relatively new here.