# angular translate using useStaticFilesLoader to load nested json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I have a nested json structure like this

```
    {
        "module1": {
            "component1": "text1",
            "component2": "text2" 
        }   
    }
```

So inside my code I am using `{"module1.component1" | translate}` which never get resolved whereas if I do

```
    {      
        "component1": "text1",
        "component2": "text2"           
    }
```

`{"component1" | translate}` works . Is there a way to resolve nested JSON data using `useStaticFilesLoader`

edit 1:
here is my useStaticFilesLoader config looks like :

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: './langfiles/',
        suffix: '.json'
      });
    $translate.use(lang);//lang is derived from header
```

langfiles contains :
  en_US.json etc

Comment: Are you using a translate filter? Please post your controller / create a running example via plunker or in the stackoverflow code editor. Filtering by "json" works fine with either data so your translate filter is where the issue most likely lies.

Comment: @Enkode: I am not sure you followed my question . As mentioned in question there is no issue when I am trying to get a flat json file but issue is when there is a nested json data then path is not resolved by the angular-translate filter like {"this.is.nested.data" | translate} whereas this works { "data" | translate} .  Anyways let me know if you need more information .

Comment: I did not understand your question because you did not explicitly say you you were using the $translateProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post: [Accessing nested JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371732/accessing-nested-json-objects) and see if that helps. Their JSFiddle show how it can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/z1uLjg89/

```js
// Including ngTranslate
angular.module("ngTranslate", ["ng"]).config(["$provide", function (n) {
    $TranslateProvider = function () {
        var n, t = {};
        this.translations = function (n, r) {
            if (!n && !r) return t;
            if (n && !r) {
                if (angular.isString(n)) return t[n];
                t = n
            } else t[n] = r
        }, this.uses = function (r) {
            if (!r) return n;
            if (!t[r]) throw Error("$translateProvider couldn't find translationTable for langKey: '" + r + "'");
            n = r
        }, this.$get = ["$interpolate", "$log", function (r, a) {
            return $translate = function (e, i) {
                var l = n ? t[n][e] : t[e];
                return l ? r(l)(i) : (a.warn("Translation for " + e + " doesn't exist"), e)
            }
        }]
    }, n.provider("$translate", $TranslateProvider)
}]), angular.module("ngTranslate").directive("translate", ["$filter", "$interpolate", function (n, t) {
    var r = n("translate");
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: !0,
        link: function (n, a, e) {
            e.$observe("translate", function (r) {
                n.translationId = angular.equals(r, "") ? t(a.text())(n.$parent) : r
            }), e.$observe("values", function (t) {
                n.interpolateParams = t
            }), n.$watch("translationId + interpolateParams", function () {
                a.html(r(n.translationId, n.interpolateParams))
            })
        }
    }
}]), angular.module("ngTranslate").filter("translate", ["$parse", "$translate", function (n, t) {
    return function (r, a) {
        return angular.isObject(a) || (a = n(a)()), t(r, a)
    }
}]);

// Configuring your module, asking for ngTranslate as dependency
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTranslate']);

// Configuring $translateProvider
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {

    // Simply register translation table as object hash
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        "SEARCH": {
            "SEARCH": "Recherce",
                "ABILITY": "Abilities",
                "MANAGEMENT": "Management Competencies",
                "PERSONAL": "Personal Suitability"
        },

            "ABILITIES": {
            "TITLE": "Test Title here",
                "ADVISORY": {
                "TITLE": "Advisory Skills",
                    "QUESTIONS": [{
                    "TYPE": "A",
                        "LEVEL": "45",
                        "DESCRIPTION": "Can you tell me how awesome you are"
                }, {
                    "TYPE": "B",
                        "LEVEL": "100",
                        "DESCRIPTION": "Tell me about your wicked project"
                }]
            }
        },

            "HEADLINE": "Oh No!",
            "SUB_HEADLINE": "Looks like you are not amazing"
    });

    var list = $translateProvider.translations('en');
    console.log(list);
    var getTitle = list.HEADLINE;
    var getSearch = list.SEARCH.ABILITY;
    console.log(getSearch);
    console.log(getTitle);
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp"></div>
```

A possible work around is to **flatten your json file**.

[Fastest way to flatten / un-flatten nested JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098797/fastest-way-to-flatten-un-flatten-nested-json-objects) or 
[Convert complex JavaScript object to dot notation object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218745/convert-complex-javascript-object-to-dot-notation-object)

This fiddle shows you how what it will look like: http://fiddle.jshell.net/blowsie/S2hsS/show/light/