# angular-translate nested JSON and filter

Tags: angularjs, json, filter, nested, angular-translate

When using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) I can filter my strings like so:

```
<ANY>{{'TRANSLATION_ID' | translate}}</ANY>
```

It works very well with the following flat JSON:

```
 {
  TRANSLATION_ID: 'A value',
};
```

However, I can't figure out how to get it to work using nested translations:

```
<ANY>{{'NAMESPACE.TRANSLATION_ID' | translate}}</ANY>
```

And the nested JSON:

```
{
    "NAMESPACE": {
         "TRANSLATION_ID": "A value"
    }
};
```

I am successfully loading the translation using `$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({prefix: 'i18n/locale-', suffix: '.json'});`, and I make use of other functions of the provider such as `$translateProvider.addInterpolation('$translateMessageFormatInterpolation');`.

The [documentation](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide) shows examples of nested translation using the [service](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service) directly, but not the [filter](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/04_using-translate-filter).

[I found a possibly related issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537395/angular-translate-using-usestaticfilesloader-to-load-nested-json).
First of all, using the code in the JSFifddle breaks the `$translateProvider` functions (I got it somehow fixed by extending the replacing variable like so: `$TranslateProvider = angular.extend(m, $TranslateProvider);` after injecting `$translateProvider` as `m` and add `pascalprecht.translate` as a module dependency, and add `var` declarations to be able to `'use strict'`) - so right off the bat it doesn't seem to be a solid solution.

With that JSFiddle code, I got the *directive* to work, at least for non-nested cases (which are fine and all, but not what's needed here, so I didn't bother testing the nested cases) but not the filter (which I need working for both nested and non-nested translations).

It seems to me namespaced translations should be a pretty big deal, and therefore should be available for all the 3 translation methods (service, directive and filter).

"service" method is rather limited ($translate service doesn't provide a two-way data binding which means more code to listen to events - [see doc](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service#using-$translate-service_things-to-keep-in-mind) - and, well, the fact that loading all the interface's string translation in the app's controller/service seems to be a pretty bad practice ; views/templates are here for that if I'm not mistaken).

Has anyone found a solution to that, or is that angular-translate nested JSON works only for the service?

Comment: Seems like I found how to make it work without using extra code. What's frustrating is that I don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know where I messed up now - the dreadful end comma in my nested translation:

```
{
    "NAMESPACE": {
         "TRANSLATION_ID": "A value",
         "ANOTHER_ID": "Another value",
    }
};
```

So, yeah, totally unrelated.

Comment: What about that comma? Should it be there or not? Either way it does not work for me sadly.

Comment: My bad for not making it more precise - it should NOT be there after "Another value" in the above example. Not quite sure why it does not work in your case though. Thanks for pointing this out, and good luck!